# django - What does this line achieve here?

Tags: python, html, django

I'm following a tutorial on effectivedjango.com, and this is the code they have:

views.py:

```
class CreateContactView(CreateView):
    model = Contact
    template_name = 'edit_contact.html'
    fields = '__all__'   #this is needed for error msg Using ModelFormMixin (base class of CreateContactView) without the 'fields' attribute is prohibited.
    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('contacts-list')
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CreateContactView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['action'] = reverse('contacts-new')   
        return context

class UpdateContactView(UpdateView):
    model = Contact
    template_name = 'edit_contact.html'
    fields = '__all__'
    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('contacts-list')
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(UpdateContactView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['action'] = reverse('contacts-edit', kwargs={'pk' : self.get_object().id})
        return context
```

urls.py:

```
url(r'^$', contacts.views.ListContactView.as_view(),
    name='contacts-list',),
url(r'^new$', contacts.views.CreateContactView.as_view(),
    name='contacts-new',),
url(r'^edit/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', contacts.views.UpdateContactView.as_view(),
    name='contacts-edit',),
```

contact_list.html:

```
{% block content %}
<h1>Contacts</h1>

<ul>
  {% for contact in object_list %}
    <li class="contact">
      <a href="{{ contact.get_absolute_url }}">{{ contact }}</a>
      (<a href="{% url "contacts-edit" pk=contact.id %}">edit</a>)
    </li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>

<a href="{% url "contacts-new" %}">Add contact</a>
{% endblock %}
```

edit_contact.html:

```
{% block content %}

{% if contact.id %}
<h1>Edit Contact</h1>
{% else %}
<h1>Add Contact</h1>
{% endif %}

<form action="{{ action }}" method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
<ul>
{{ form.as_ul }}
</ul>
<input id="save_contact" type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>

<a href="{% url "contacts-list" %}">Back to list</a>
{% if contact.id %}
<a href="{% url "contacts-delete" pk=contact.id %}">Delete</a>
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Why does the line `context['action'] = reverse('contacts-edit', kwargs={'pk' : self.get_object().id})` in `views.py` look like its calling itself?

What I mean is, this action is called when the submit button is pressed in the `contact-edit` template, correct? So it starts there, and it is reverse-calling `contact-edit` which is itself, right?

What am I not seeing here?

Thank you for all your help.

Comment: Yes, an `UpdateView` points to itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes,** the line `context['action'] = reverse('contacts-edit', kwargs={'pk' : self.get_object().id})` in `views.py` is calling itself. This line generates the proper url for `contacts-edit` view.

This is done so that `POST` requests come to the same view i.e. `UpdateContactView` which is an [`UpdateView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#updateview). There, proper handling will be done i.e. form validation will occur with the sent data. If the form is valid, object will be updated. Otherwise, the form will be displayed again with errors.

Django docs on `UpdateView`:

> A view that displays a form for editing an existing object,
>   redisplaying the form with validation errors (if there are any) and
>   saving changes to the object.